# Entity Framework Core : multiple relationships between tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a simple data model in which I would like two relationships between my `UserAccount` and my `Affiliation` entity. One of them is a many-to-many and the other is just a one-to-many relationship.

Here are my model classes:

```
public class UserAccount
{
    public UserAccount()
    {
        this.Affiliations = new List<Affiliation>();
        this.Entitlments = new HashSet<Entitlment>(); 
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserAccountId { get; set; }
    public String? Name { get; set; }
    public Affiliation PrimaryAffiliation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Affiliation> Affiliations { get; set; }  
}
    
public class Affiliation
{
    public Affiliation() 
    {
        this.UserAccounts = new HashSet<UserAccount>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int AffiliationID { get; set; }
    public string? AffiliationName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

A `UserAccount` can have multiple `Affiliations` and a single primary affiliation. After adding the `PrimaryAffiliation` property to the `UserAccount` class, I am adding a migration which builds ok, but it causes the following error:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Affiliation.UserAccounts' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

I attempted to fix this by adding:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
                .HasOne<Affiliation>(a => a.PrimaryAffiliation);
}
```

Is it possible to have both of these relationships or is there a better approach?

Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: I don't understand...it looks to me like you have a many to many relationship?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have a many to many relationship for the 'Affiliations' property (ICollection).  I am trying to add the PrimaryAffiliation property that will reference the Affiliation Class. 

A user account can have multiple Affiliations but only one PrimaryAffiliation.

Comment: Looks like you should add a foreign key of `PrimaryAffiliationId` to `UserAccount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need specify a foreignkey `AffiliationId` in entity `UserAccount` and another `public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts_one_many { get; set; }` for this one-to-many relationship. 
Another problem you will meet is

> "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints"

This could be solved by adding `[DeleteBehavior(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)]`.
Try following sample:
UserAccount.cs

```
    public class UserAccount
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserAccountId { get; set; }
        public String? Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Affiliation> Affiliations { get; set; }

        public int AffiliationId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AffiliationId")]
        [DeleteBehavior(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)]
        public Affiliation PrimaryAffiliation { get; set; }
    }
```

Affiliation.cs

```
    public class Affiliation
    {
        [Key]
        public int AffiliationID { get; set; }
        public string? AffiliationName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts_one_many { get; set; }
    }
```

MyContext.cs

```
    public class MyContext :DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=192.168.2.68;Initial Catalog=test189;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxx;TrustServerCertificate=True");
        }

        public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts_table { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Affiliation> Affiliations_table { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Affiliations)
                .WithMany(a => a.UserAccounts);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
                .HasOne(u => u.PrimaryAffiliation)
                .WithMany(a => a.UserAccounts_one_many);
        }
    }
```

update-database Result
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  This was exactly what I was trying to accomplish.  I was having trouble determining the correct pattern (adding the second virtual ICollection).  I had tried something very similar to what you suggested with the modelbuilder but I was trying to reference the same UserAccounts collection.  

Again thanks so much for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case:

> A UserAccount can have multiple Affiliations and a single primary
> affiliation.

You should add `PrimaryAffiliationId`

```
public class UserAccount
{
    //...
    public int? PrimaryAffiliationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Affiliation PrimaryAffiliation { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add `HasForeignKey(u => u.PrimaryAffiliationId)`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
            .HasOne<Affiliation>(a => a.PrimaryAffiliation)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.PrimaryAffiliationId);
```

Not so sure this is needed: `.HasOne<Affiliation>(a => a.PrimaryAffiliation)` try to delete it and update.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the suggestion, however as soon as I add the:

public virtual Affiliation PrimaryAffiliation { get; set; } the migration The exception 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Affiliation.UserAccounts' of type 'ICollection<UserAccount>' error.

The HasForeignKey property is not available in EF Core.

Comment: Ok this is a new problem, I'll need to set a test environment